# Write rdf file without Alphabetical

Tags: rdf, jena, rdfs

Write RDF

I have a model RDF and I want write it in a file. This would be the result:

```
@prefix dc:      <http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/> .
@prefix legal:   <http://www.linked-usdl.org/ns/usdl-legal#> .
@prefix foaf:    <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix vann:    <http://purl.org/vocab/vann/> .
@prefix org:     <http://www.w3.org/ns/org#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix price:   <http://www.linked-usdl.org/ns/usdl-price#> .
@prefix usdl:    <http://www.linked-usdl.org/ns/usdl#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix dei:     <http://dei.uc.pt/rdf/dei#> .
@prefix gr:      <http://purl.org/goodrelations/v1#> .
@prefix skos:    <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#> .

rdf:Standard_M1__Small_default
      rdfs:CPU "1 EC2 Compute Unit (1 virtual core with 1 EC2 Compute Unit)"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:RAM "1.7"^^xsd:float ;
      rdfs:Platform "32-bit"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:Storage "160"^^xsd:float .
      rdfs:IOPerformance "Moderate"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:EBS-OptimizedAvailable
              "false"^^xsd:boolean ;
      rdfs:OS "Linux/UNIX"^^xsd:string ;
      rdfs:Cost "0.08"^^xsd:float ;
```

But, when execute model.write(out, lang);, the triples are in alphabetical order (CPU,COST, ESB...). When I create the model, put the properties in the order I want and work. But when i write the model, it is arranges in alphabetical order. How can I disregard the alphabetical order to write the RDF model? Another question, this rdf file is correct?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The RDF isn't legal

#### Missing `.` at end

Your RDF file in the question isn't well formed.  A form like

```
s p1 o1 ;
  p2 o2 ;
  p3 o3 .
```

Should end with a period.  It looks like you might be showing us just the first few lines of your file.

#### Defining your own terms in the RDF and RDFS namespaces

This might not technically be prohibited, but in some serializations, terms in the RDF namespace that aren't actually RDF vocabulary will cause warnings, so terms like `rdf:Standard_M1__Small_default` and `rdfs:Platform` are probably a bad idea.  E.g., see

> ### [5.1 The RDF Namespace and Vocabulary](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-rdf-syntax/#section-Namespace)
>
> The RDF Vocabulary is identified by this namespace name and consists
>   of the following names only: … Any other names are not defined and
>   SHOULD generate a warning when encountered, but should otherwise
>   behave normally.

### The order doesn't matter

RDF is a *graph* based data representation.  An RDF graph is a *set* of triples, and sets don't have order.  The same RDF graph can be serialized in lots of different ways.  Turtle *is* more human readable and writeable than some formats, but it's just a representation of an *unordered* data format.  Because it's a unordered data representation, there's no real reason for an implementation to remember the order in which you added things.  As such, there's probably no easy way to maintain any particular order for the serialization.

Comment: Thanks for your help! But for me the order is important, because when I read the file, I need that the properties are in the order they were added.

Comment: It's not clear why you "need" that. The order of triples in the file doesn't change the graph.  When Jena reads the triples, they're put into a graph, and the order that they appeared in the file is not preserved.  Since order doesn't matter, it's very unlikely that any standard tool is going to make it easy to suddenly preserve ordering.  Why is it important in your case?

Comment: @GabrielaCavalcante It's also a bad idea to define your own vocabulary in the rdf: and rdfs: namespaces.  See the quote in the updated answer.

Comment: The project code reads the rdf file and makes a comparison. Each statement is evaluated, and this evaluation follows a sequence (CPU, RAM, Platform, Storage, IOPerformance, EBS-OptimizedAvailable, OS and COST). I used this sequence when I created affirmations.

Comment: Well, then you're not actually working with RDF, because you're not treatting it as RDf, but rather you're working with text files that have a superficial similarity to RDF.  If you want to treat it as RDF, then read the RDF model in and do your validation on the model, not the text file.

Comment: via Google translate, you wrote, "if this is wrong, I will modify my code to read everything in sequence. but first, i was wondering if it is possible to not order the model."  Models *aren't* ordered.  a serialization has to put some text before other text, but that's just an artifact of the serialization.  If someone says "this box contains a red ball and a blue ball" and you write a test that "the first ball I take out should be blue and the second should be red", then the **test** is wrong, not the box, because you could pull them out in either order.

Comment: ok,understand. I'll modify the code to read the RDF correctly.

Comment: Ok, I think I explained wrong. The verification I do is to know which of the rdf file describes the service you want. I don't available the RDF file, but I see that it has the service you desire. I think I explained a little better. But the order is only a detail, I'll fix my code.